# Qual è il significato di "ventura" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Questa frase, tratta dal romanzo *Artemisia* di Anna Banti, descrive quello che pensano della pittrice nella Corte di Inghilterra:

> Donna bizzarra, più di **ventura** che virtuosa, e se non fosse stato suo padre, mai l'avremmo chiamata da queste bande.

Ho cercato il significato di "ventura" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che significa "sorte", "fortuna", "destino". Tuttavia non capisco il senso di questo vocabolo nella frase precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: In italiano moderno è *avventura*.

Comment: @egreg: Tuttavia non riesco a cogliere il senso dell'espressione "di ventura" o "di avventura" in confronto con "virtuosa" come qualificativo della pittrice.

Comment: @egreg:  Adesso mi sono accorta che il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ventura/) parla di *medico, chirurgo di ventura*: che esercita la professione libera, che non ha condotta. Potrebbe essere questo il significato?

Comment: Non credo: “dedita più alle avventure che alla virtù”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Virtuosa* potrebbe essere letto come persona dotata di virtù con doti morali.

*Di ventura* in questo contesto potrebbe essere nell'accezione di mercenaria, persona che agisce solo per tornaconto personale non badando a questioni etiche o ideologiche, quindi senza grandi virtù.

Parlando di Corte di Inghilterra, probabilmente si vuole mettere in evidenza che la pittrice era stata presa in considerazione solo in virtù del padre (forse persona stimata), dal momento che lei non brillava per particolari doti morali apprezzate generalmente a corte.

Comment: Questa interpretazione è coerente con una delle interpretazioni dell'enigmatico verso 61 del II canto dell'Inferno, in cui Beatrice definisce Dante «l'amico mio, e non della ventura». Una delle letture più accreditate è appunto che Dante perseguisse la dottrina delle cose divine (personificata da Beatrice) di per sé e non ambendo a ricompense o vantaggi.

Comment: Ma questa non sarebbe più o meno la definizione del Treccani: "che esercita la professione libera, che non ha condotta"? L'unico è che il Treccani applica questa definizione a un medico o a un chirurgo e non a una pittrice.

Answer (score 2):

Il senso generale di “ventura”, come si diceva, è quello di “sorte”, “destino”. Di qui ha però assunto accezioni specifiche in locuzioni specifiche.

Nell'italiano contemporaneo si usa quasi solo nella locuzione “andare alla ventura”, cioè affidarsi al caso, e per i “capitani di ventura”, che più che al caso si affidavano a chi pagava di più. E a pensarci, anche “fortuna” – che nell'accezione classica poteva essere positiva o negativa e in quella moderna è quasi solo positiva – ha un senso relativo al successo economico (“ha gudagnato una fortuna”).

Il richiamo a questi mercenari può far pensare che a quel personaggio di *Artemisia* si attribuiscano interessi materiali e quasi meschini (non a caso, “mercenaria” si dice anche di una prostituta).

Questa interpretazione è coerente con una delle interpretazioni dell'enigmatico verso 61 del II canto dell'Inferno, in cui Beatrice definisce Dante «l'amico mio, e non della ventura». Una delle letture più accreditate è appunto che Dante perseguisse la dottrina delle cose divine (personificata da Beatrice) di per sé e non ambendo a ricompense o vantaggi.

Quindi queste considerazioni, insieme alla contrapposizione alla virtù, fanno pensare che chi parla considera la pittrice nella migliore delle ipotesi poco costante nelle sue intenzioni, e nella peggiore attaccata a bassi interessi materiali.